# Emoji regression in ActiveSupport json output

Tags: ruby, json, activesupport

I have found what I believe to be a regression in ActiveSupport 3.2.14. Here you can see the output of JSON.encode in ActiveSupport 3.2.13:

[image]

Here, in 3.2.14:

[image]

This is a breaking change for my use case and as a result I cannot upgrade to 3.2.14 without solving this. I believe [this is the change that regressed my code](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c910388587220e962682b0b9187e79b8f1641c17).

Can someone with more experience in this area than I explain if this is by design, a regression, and why?

---

**NOTE**

If you want the raw text to run this line in your console, here is everything including the escaping for the emoji:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(["\360\237\230\204"])
```

Comment: give the raw code instead of image..which help us to run your code in our editor.

Comment: Do not post images of text, instead copy-and-paste the actual text directly into your post. Images of text are not easily parsable, searchable, or accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with the author of the change to which I linked. He said while they are aware they have regressed emoji with this change, they are not considering a fix, and to upgrade to 4.0. Thus, I will not be upgrading to 3.2.14, or if I do, I will have to monkeypatch.